# BadMethodCallException : Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::offers does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to do php artisan db:seed on **Laravel 5.6.39** and getting an error:

> **BadMethodCallException  : Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::offers does not exist.**

Offer Model code:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Offer extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

Task Model

```
public function offers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Offer::class);
}
```

Databaseseeder file

```
factory(App\Task::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($task) {
    return $task->offers()->save(factory(App\Offer::class)->make());
});
```

What am I not doing right?

Comment: well it seems to think there isn't an `offers` method on `App\Task`

Comment: @lagbox could u be more elaborate? thx,

Comment: well the first thing is how do you know that the code you are showing from the seeder is causing this?

Comment: When I comment out the code below and run db:seed, the error does not occur factory(App\Task::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($task) {
    return $task->offers()->save(factory(App\Offer::class)->make());
});

Comment: PHP doesn't seem to think that `App\Task` has an `offers` method or the visibility isn't `public`

Answer (score -1):

Update your DatabaseSeeder to this and check

```
factory(App\Task::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($task) {
    return $task->offers()->save(factory(App\Offer::class)->create());
});
```

Comment: @DanielOmara How you are running the application if via `php artian serve` then restart it